# Extract TFS Changeset difference to excel

Tags: excel, api, powershell, tfs

I am a big fan of stackoverflow & have got many solutions from here.
Recently I have hit a roadblock.
**I want to compare two change-sets in TFS 2013 and extract the changes to an excel file in a customized format**.
I will explain in detail

**There is a folder "ABC" in TFS. I want to compare the first & the latest change set of this folder from history & then move through all the changed files & extract the changes to an excel file.**

**I cannot use any third party comparison tool like "winmerge" or "beyond compare".**

Is there a way to accomplish exactly what i am looking for using TFS API/ Powershell etc?
Any help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A great post which discusses more detailed information how to compare trees at different versions by using TFS API from Buck Hodge. Please check: https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/buckh/2006/04/06/how-to-compare-diff-trees-at-different-versions-using-the-api/ (Strongly recommended)

Here is also a good example of TFS API to get history, download file, compare files(But used the winmerge) http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/243655/TFS-SDK-Compare-Changesets-programmatically. You can use `diffFiles(X,X)` instead it, a example code for it:

```
using (var projectCollection = new TfsTeamProjectCollection(new Uri(repositoryUrl))) 
  {
    projectCollection.EnsureAuthenticated();
    var versionControlServer = (VersionControlServer)projectCollection.GetService(typeof(VersionControlServer));

    string path = "$/MyProject/path/to/file.xml"

    var before = new DiffItemVersionedFile(versionControlServer, path, VersionSpec.ParseSingleSpec(minRevision.ToString(), null));
    var after = new DiffItemVersionedFile(versionControlServer, path, VersionSpec.ParseSingleSpec(maxRevision.ToString(), null));

    using (var stream = new MemoryStream())
    using (var writer = new StreamWriter(stream))
    {
        var options = new DiffOptions();
        options.Flags = DiffOptionFlags.EnablePreambleHandling;
        options.OutputType = DiffOutputType.Unified;
        options.TargetEncoding = Encoding.UTF8;
        options.SourceEncoding = Encoding.UTF8;
        options.StreamWriter = writer;
        Difference.DiffFiles(versionControlServer, before, after, options, path, true);
        writer.Flush();

       var diff = Encoding.UTF8.GetString(stream.ToArray());
    } 
  }
```

Comment: Thanks..Patrick.. I was able to write the differences to a text file. But I would like to get that into an excel file in a more customized format..let's say just the differences to an excel column. Is there a readymade parser available in C# for that .. Tried ParseDiff but unable to find any documentation.. Is there any alternative to do that ?

Comment: Did you mean you just want to  put the content in the excel through C#? Here is a Official introduction about it https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/kb/302084

Comment: No...Here is what I am looking for ..Lets say TFS generates the following diff @@ -212,8 +223,8 @@
       </XYZ>
       <modules>
         Some text ABC
-        <New_tag_part1>AAAAAAA</New_tag_part1>
-        <New_tag_part2>BBBBBBB </New_tag_part2>
+        <New_tag_part1> CCCCCC </New_tag_part1>
+        <New_tag_part2> DDDDDD </New_tag_part2> I want to read & create an excel with columns like Deleted Text & Added Text. Is there a parser which can read Unified diff and I can use in .Net ?

Comment: I'm not sure about this. As far as I know, there is no off-the-shelf parser. Suggest you to create a new thread to discuss this question adding C# or .Net tag . This will also make answer searching in the forum easier and be beneficial to other community members as well.